# Is there a better way to replace number to alphabet

Tags: c#

I have made a code that works but Is there a way to make it better

```
byte[] r = Convert.FromBase64String("XFEWtnopccImhpHTzGeoeXBg4ws=");
string c = BitConverter.ToString(r).Replace("-", string.Empty);
string h = c.Replace("A", "K").Replace("B", "L").Replace("C", "M").Replace("D", "N").Replace("E", "O")
    .Replace("F", "P").Replace("0", "A").Replace("1","B").Replace("2", "C").Replace("3", "D").Replace("4", "E")
    .Replace("5", "F").Replace("6", "G").Replace("7", "H").Replace("8", "I")
    .Replace("9", "J");
Console.WriteLine(h.ToLower());
```

It replace `0-9` with `A-J` example `0-A | 1-B | 2-C`
and it replace
`A-F` with `K-P` example `A-K | B-L | C-M`

output must be:
`fmfbbglghkcjhbmccgigjbndmmghkihjhagaodal`

**Note**: that this works I only want to know If there is a easier way to do that.

EDIT:
Thanxs for all the answers I really dont know which one is the best one but I think that one I marked as answered should be it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BitConverter.ToString(r).Replace()` stuff is an awful detour.

```
const string lookup = "abcdefghijklmnop";

byte[] r = Convert.FromBase64String("XFEWtnopccImhpHTzGeoeXBg4ws=");
string h = string.Concat(r.Select(b => "" +  lookup[b >> 4] + lookup[b & 0xf]));

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(h == "fmfbbglghkcjhbmccgigjbndmmghkihjhagaodal");
```

---

Optimized code:

```
const string lookup = "abcdefghijklmnop";
public string Decode(string input)
{
    byte[] buf = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    var result = new StringBuilder(buf.Length*2);
    foreach (byte b in buf)
    {
        result.Append(lookup[b >> 4]).Append(lookup[b & 0xf]);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}

string h = Decode("XFEWtnopccImhpHTzGeoeXBg4ws=");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(h == "fmfbbglghkcjhbmccgigjbndmmghkihjhagaodal");
```

Comment: This is cool! I'm playing with some benchmarks for fun, and I had high hopes for the simple bit shifts, but it surprising about doubles the run time. https://dotnetfiddle.net/cwRu1v

Comment: Here we go! Now I have a version of this that kicks the snot out of anything else. I knew it should be possible https://dotnetfiddle.net/773zEK

Comment: For reference: typical run of my optimized version of this technique is 1300-1500 ticks. Typical run of the original code is 10,000 to 11,500 ticks. Next best option (my String.Create code) averages 2600 to 2800 ticks. I suspect most of that time is this saves an entire string allocation, which is probably close to 1000 ticks on it's own.

Comment: Okay, I promoted the optimized code to the answer. It deserves to live somewhere more visible than behind the .Net Fiddle link. If you don't like it, you can edit to remove it.

Comment: Also: I realized my stringbuilder tests where out-performing my String.Create tests (which is surprising! -- but that's why we test). So one final edit that runs even faster. https://dotnetfiddle.net/wHgWA4

Comment: Joel, on this scale I would always go for readability an brevity, my first version. That new `String.Create<>` looked nice but when you want to optimize on this level: avoid lambdas.

Comment: @HenkHolterman hey I never know that we can remove that BitConverter what do you mean by optimized code? is that the sam as the first one?

Comment: No, Joel edited this to add the version with the stringbuilder. Short or fast: your choice.

Answer (score 3):

You could store all your char transforms in a dictionary and then use a simple loop to replace the chars. Using a StringBuilder.Replace (using the char as input parameters overload) should be better because it avoids the constant creation of new strings at each string.Replace call and there is no worry about string size changes.

```
Dictionary<char, char> replacements = new Dictionary<char, char>
{
    {'A', 'K'}, {'B', 'L'}, {'C', 'M'}, {'D', 'N'}, {'E', 'O'}, {'F', 'P'},
    {'0', 'A'}, {'1', 'B'}, {'2', 'C'}, {'3', 'D'}, {'4', 'E'}, {'5', 'F'},
    {'6', 'G'}, {'7', 'H'}, {'8', 'I'}, {'9', 'J'}
};

void Main()
{

    byte[] r = Convert.FromBase64String("XFEWtnopccImhpHTzGeoeXBg4ws=");
    string c = BitConverter.ToString(r).Replace("-", string.Empty);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(c);
    foreach(char x in replacements.Keys)
        sb.Replace(x, replacements[x]);
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString().ToLower());
 }
```

Comment: much better thanxs you!

Comment: Why do a replace?  Why not just start with an empty `StringBuilder` and just use `Add`?  `sb.Add(replacments[x]);`  I wonder if there is more overhead in that `Replace` call.

Comment: What if there are characters that you shouldn't replace? We need to introduce an if with a seek. Then we should check if the performances are better. Possible.

Comment: True.  The Base64 string seemed to only contain hex digits and hyphens but your solution accounts for unexpected characters.

Comment: We can improve on this further in with String.Create() in .Net Core... (at least performance-wise. Whether it's enough to account for the readability is another issue.

Comment: Also, this is O(n*m), where m is the size of the dictionary. I think it's possible to get down to just O(n), even using StringBuilder (see my answer for how). Of course, it's unlikely to matter for one string of this size, but it's still fun to look at ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following:

```
static string DecodeWithoutLinq(string encoded)
{
    char[] s = new char[encoded.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < encoded.Length; i++)
    {
        char currentChar = encoded[i];

        if (char.IsLetter(currentChar))
            s[i] = (char)(encoded[i] + 10);
        else if (char.IsNumber(currentChar))
            s[i] = (char)('A' + (currentChar - '0'));
    }
    return new string(s).ToLower();
}

static string DecodeWithLinq(string encoded)
{
    return string.Concat(encoded.ToCharArray()
        .Select(s => char.IsLetter(s) ? (char)(s + 10) : (char)('A' + (s - '0')))).ToLower();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] r = Convert.FromBase64String("XFEWtnopccImhpHTzGeoeXBg4ws=");
    string c = BitConverter.ToString(r).Replace("-", string.Empty);

    string decodedString1 = DecodeWithoutLinq(c);
    string decodedString2 = DecodeWithLinq(c);
    Console.WriteLine(decodedString1);
    Console.WriteLine(decodedString2);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Just one way that doesn't involve string manipulation.

DecodeWithLinq isn't verifying if it's a number though. Can be easily added if needed.

Comment: or new string(char[]), It was a mistake on my part, thanks for noticing.

Comment: that way with `DecodeWithLinq` looks like the shortest and easiest way what do you mean with `verifying`

Comment: @schokoBong just without a char.IsNumber! Do you happen to expect any other strings or chars that fall out of the specs above?

Comment: no I m not getting any other chars or string thanxs

Comment: You can remove the `ToCharArray()` call from the linq option. `string` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: You can also remove the `ToLower()` if you change up the lambda just a bit: `char.IsLetter(s) ? (char)(s + 42) : (char)('a' + (s - '0'))`

Comment: @schokoBong You should really look at the updated answer by Henk Holtman. You can run that code 7 times for every time you run this code once.

Comment: It's not so bad, though, if you unroll the linq loop with String.Create https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sfvass

Comment: One more .Net Fiddle link here with a must faster version of DecodeWithoutLinq() https://dotnetfiddle.net/Aucdoc Still runs for twice as long as the the Henk Holtman answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution which uses a couple of arrays and a bit of Linq.

```
void Main()
{
    string inputChars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    string replacementChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";

    byte[] r = Convert.FromBase64String("XFEWtnopccImhpHTzGeoeXBg4ws=");
    string c = BitConverter.ToString(r);

    string result = new String(c.Where(ch => inputChars.Contains(ch))
                                .Select(ch => replacementChars[inputChars.IndexOf(ch)])
                                .ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine(result.ToLower());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length in advance (and you do in this situation), .Net Core has an [even better option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=netstandard-2.1) than `StringBuilder` now (at least in terms of performance):

```
private static Dictionary<char, char> map = new Dictionary<char, char> {
    {'A', 'k'}, {'B', 'l'}, {'C', 'm'}, {'D', 'n'}, {'E', 'o'}, {'F', 'p'},
    {'0', 'a'},{'1', 'b'}, {'2', 'c'}, {'3', 'd'},{'4', 'e'}, {'5', 'f'},
    {'6', 'g'},{'7', 'h'},{'8', 'i'}, {'9', 'j'}
};

public static string GetMyString(string input)
{
    byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    string source = BitConverter.ToString(b);

    return string.Create(2*(input.Length+1)/3 , input, (r, d) => {
        int j = 0;
        foreach(char c in d)
        {   
            if (c == '-') continue;
            r[j++] = map[c];
        }
    });
}

Console.WriteLine(GetMyString("XFEWtnopccImhpHTzGeoeXBg4ws="));
```

If I were to use `StringBuilder`, I know I could easily remove that last `.Replace()` call and the `ToLower()` call, both of which allocate and copy whole new strings:

```
public static string GetMyString(string input)
{
    byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    string source = BitConverter.ToString(b);

    var result = new StringBuilder(2*(input.Length+1)/3);
    foreach(char c in input)
    {
        if (c == '-') continue;
        result.Append(map[c]);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

I haven't benchmarked, but I would expect this to significantly out-perform the other Dictionary/StringBuilder-based answer... but that's what I get for taking longer to answer and providing two solutions ;)

[See them in action.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Pwc7l)

Answer (score 0):

How about a regex solution?

```
    Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"A", "K"}, {"B", "L"}, {"C", "M"}, {"D", "N"}, {"E", "O"}, 
                                                                    {"F", "P"}, {"0", "A"}, {"1", "B"}, {"2", "C"}, {"3", "D"}, 
                                                                    {"4", "E"}, {"5", "F"}, {"6", "G"}, {"7", "H"}, {"8", "I"}, 
                                                                    {"9", "J"}};

    byte[] r = Convert.FromBase64String("XFEWtnopccImhpHTzGeoeXBg4ws=");
    string c = BitConverter.ToString(r).Replace("-", string.Empty);

    var regex = new Regex(String.Join("|",map.Keys));
    var newStr = regex.Replace(c, m => map[m.Value]);
    Console.WriteLine(newStr.ToLower());
```

[run it on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OPYB2V)